# Convert Screen Point to SP 4326

Tags: c#, esri

I am using Esri for .NET. I trap screen coordinates by mouse click using ScreenToLocation function. How can I convert this mappoint to SP of 4326?

```
MapPoint mapPoint = Mapview.ScreenToLocation(screenPoint);
```

My mappoint is not where I clicked on the map. I get the coordinates as 5423799.44921864,-267641.097678069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the ArcGIS Runtime for windows store or the runtime for wpf?

Anyway, you are getting a WebMercator point. In order to convert between spatial references you need to use the project method of the **GeometryService** on [wpf](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/help/index.html#//01n70000001t000000) or the **GeometryEngine** on the [winstore](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/store/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_Project.htm)

Or, if you prefer to do the conversion WebMercator (102100/3857) to WGS84 (4326) synchronously by code, you can do with:

```
private const double R_MAJOR = 6378137.0;
private const double R_MINOR = 6356752.3142;

public MapPoint PointToWGS84(double x, double y)
{        
    double originShift = 2 * Math.PI * R_MAJOR / 2.0;
    double mx = (x / originShift) * 180.0;
    double my = (y / originShift) * 180.0;
    my = (180 / Math.PI) * (2 * Math.Atan(Math.Exp(my * Math.PI / 180.0)) - Math.PI / 2.0);
    return new MapPoint(mx, my, new SpatialReference(WGS84));
}
```

To go from WGS84 to WM

```
public MapPoint PointToWM(double x, double y)
{
    double originShift = 2 * Math.PI * R_MAJOR / 2.0;
    double mx = x * originShift / 180.0;
    double my = Math.Log(Math.Tan((90.0 + y) * Math.PI / 360.0)) / (Math.PI / 180.0);
    my = my * originShift / 180.0;
    return new MapPoint(mx, my, new SpatialReference(102100));
}
```

please note that this code works ONLY for WM to/from WGS. For other conversions you must always use the GeometryService

Comment: If you'd like to learn more: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator